# "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, 64-bit, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

After migrating servers today, one site keeps getting the error above. A quick search on Google showed that it's a fairly common problem, and there are lots of fixes, so far I tried the following:

```
1. %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe –i
```

This seems to be the most common solution, however it didn't work for me. I tried running the same from v2.0.50727, just in case, and from Framework folder, even though this is 64-bit version of Windows. Didn't work.

```
2. %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client\setup.exe /repair /x86 /x64 /ia64 /parameterfolder Client /norestart
```

I repaired the framework but with no results, I still get the same error.

```
3. Adding <add name="ManagedEngine64" image="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll" 
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" /> to applicationHost.config, mine was actually completely empty - but that didn't help either.
```

The weird thing is that we have a number of sites running, all of them .NET4 and all working correctly - this is the only one running on v2 and it seems to me that it's the root of the trouble.

Short of re-installing the IIS, can you think of any better options? I'd rather not cause disruption to the service of the other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was migration from 32 to 64-bit environment. The application pool on which the website was running had `Enable 32-bit applications` setting set to `false`, so I guess it thought 32-bit handlers were corrupt.
In addition a chunk of web.config was missing, which caused problems after application pool was fixed, but was also much easier to locate.